# How do you change the font colour of the Radiogroup component in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, radio-group

I have a Radiogroup component in my Delphi project and I would like to change the colour of the font of the Radiogroup. I have tried `.font.color:=clwhite` but this doesn't work. The other aspects of font can be changed but not the colour. Im using Delphi 2010

Comment: In most cases, it is best to use the system default colours. Changing the font colour of a radio button caption is rather involved. You are not "supposed" to do that.

Comment: With runtime themes enabled (the default setting), the `RadioGroup.Items` are painted with the color of the theme. If you disable runtime themes (untick `Project - Options - Application - Enable runtime themes`), you can change `RadioGroup.Font.Color`, (the color will only show up at runtime) which is common for both the `RadioGroup` header and the items. If you, instead of a `TRadioGroup`, use a `TGroupBox` with separate `TRadioButton`s and disable runtime themes, you can assign individual colors to the `TRadioButton`s. Again, the colors are only visible at runtime.